# Thunar doesn't recognize SD cards

Tags: drivers, usb, mount, sd-card

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3 LTS inside two desktop PCs and one laptop, all of them are 64 bit systems.

Inside one of my desktop PCs, I have a Multi-Card Reader USB 2.0.

[image: Multi-Card Reader USB 2.0]

That device worked so fine all of those years. But, this year, I have tried to use it to read files from my photographic camera SD cards and I cannot to see it with Thunar, or GParted, or any other files manager:

[image: Thunar doesn't see the SD card]

But, the device is recognized with the System Information Tool:

[image: System Information Tool]

The red led is lighting (ON), below the adapter USB port, each time I insert the cards.

What's wrong here?

Is it something related with some this year (2021) upgrading?

Could it be something related with the SD cards type and/or format?

Do I have something missed, here?

Comment: Get more information. Watch `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect the card/card reader.

Comment: As above, the log may give some clue. And be prepared for the possibility of hardware failure.

Comment: It seems to me like the card has some rare issue, because I tested 10 different cards and just that card (from the Canon camera) has problems. Maybe it is about some specific parameters of that card. I don't know.